# I faced an error "Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root '######' failed to load coreclr." after upgrading my site to DotNet 6

Tags: .net-core, iis, runtime, version

I have upgrade my site from DotNet Core 2.1 to DotNet 6. It seems to work fine for couple of days. Then it started to crash in random interval of time. I checked in the Event Log to find out the cause of this issue and I found the following error message.
"Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\....' failed to load coreclr. Exception message: Managed server didn't initialize after 4****** ms."

It seems to be issue with ".Net Runtime" and "IIS AspNet Core Module V2".But I have not found the solution to stop from my site getting crashed.

I have changed the AspNet Hosting model from "Inprocess" to "OutOfProcess" too But it did not work. I also added the StartUptime but it did not work either.

Comment: Please attach a report to the question, so that others can see how you configured the site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: What error status code did you get? Please provide as much detailed error information as possible. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on IIS.

Comment: I got the Error Code 500.37

Answer (score 0):

> 500.37 - ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit

This happens when there are many application pools on the same machine, Microsoft recommends to stagger the startup process of multiple applications.

Another solution is to increase the start up limit, I suggest you can try increasing startupTimeLimit and try again, element in web.config has an option < aspNetCore > (You can refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configuration-with-webconfig))

```
    <system.webServer>
      <aspNetCore xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(startupTimeLimit)" startupTimeLimit="400">
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
```